# New-AzureDeployment times out on package upload

Tags: powershell, deployment, azure

I'm trying to automate our deployment to Azure process. I've gone through [various](http://mooneyblog.mmdbsolutions.com/index.php/2013/01/23/windows-azure-4-deploying-via-powershell/) [pages](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2012/09/11/ci-deployment-of-azure-web-roles-using-teamcity.aspx) from google [with powershell](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/continuous-delivery/) [scripts examples](http://coderead.wordpress.com/2012/10/19/automating-cloud-service-deployment-in-azure/).

I've narrowed down the problem to this part:

```
# publish - here I get 500 server error -(
New-AzureDeployment -Slot "Staging" -Package $package -Configuration $configuration -ServiceName $service
```

And I get error message:
[image: error message]

Looking at `$Error` variable (specifically at this `$Error[0].Exception.InnerException.Response`) I can see that the request timed out:
[image: Error request]

**Operation could not be completed within the specified time**

I have tried uploading package file (4 Mb - plain vanilla MVC4 app from Empty template) to azure and in in `$package` variable giving the url:

```
New-AzureDeployment -Slot "Staging" -Package "https://blah.blob.core.windows.net/shared/blah.cspkg" -Configuration $configuration -ServiceName $service
```

And the publish went almost instantly and now I can access the staging instance with the latest changes.

Does this mean that Azure publishing service has timeout period and my shady internet connection speed does not allow to push the file within this timeout?
It took me 4 minutes to upload the file via CoudXplorer and this is the plain vanilla app with nothing in it. The real app is 10 times larger.

Is there anything can be done for that? Or I'll just have to upload packages to Azure storage first and publish from there?

**Update** Confirmed - that is the internet connection. I have spinned up a virtual machine in Azure cloud, set up all the required scripts there and tried to deploy a package as a local file and it worked fine - deployed as expected, no error messages. Azure, why can't you specify a timeout? some people still live with ADSL and 0.3Mbit upload speed -(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the API for the Management Service - see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233298/continuous-deployment-delivery/16243577#16243577).  We had lots of similar issues deploying from PS, so we ended up copying the deployment package to the BLOB on build and then running PS or REST API commands from there to deploy.  There is a build & copy to BLOB example in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324656/windows-azure-multiple-deployment/15331392#15331392).

Comment: So you discarded powershell and make your own command line application(s) for deployment? Is your build script running on your server or in Azure?

Comment: We run the Build script on the TFS Build Server as a build task in the project.